# Fedora 17 Freezes on Boot

Tags: fedora, boot, freeze

I have been having issues with Fedora 17 not booting after the latest round of updates. I am able to enter the pass for my disk encryption, the boot logo acts normally but after the animation is complete, the boot fails to progress further.

I checked the diagnostics and it seems that there is an issue in plymouth-quit-wait.service. When I check systemctl status on this service, I am informed that the service has been loaded but timed out when start was attempted.

I have tried disabling the system using systemctl disable plymouth-quit-wait.service with and without the force option, with no success.

I am really lost here, I'm not even sure what exactly isn't working. What can I do to fix this issue, or at least troubleshoot it further?

Answer (score 4):

This is [a bug in Fedora 17](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=817462).

You can work around it by disabling the Plymouth boot screen:

```
systemctl mask plymouth-start.service
```

It will be fixed in Fedora 18.

Comment: Note: It hasn't been fixed in Fedora 18

Comment: @user30371: the bug indicates that it *was* fixed in F18. Either the fix is incomplete (or incorrect), or you have a new problem. Please reopen that bug if the circumstances are exactly the same, or else file a new one. Thank you!